# How to join strings in a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capitalise the first character of each word and join all words into one string. I have managed to capitalise the first character of each word but cant seem to get .join() to work on the final result

```
function generateHashtag (str) {

 let split = str.split(' ')

 for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i++){

  let finalResult = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].substring(1)

   console.log(finalResult.join(''))

  }


}

console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is')) should return ('HelloMyNameIs')
```

Comment: `finalResult` is a `String`, not an `Array` so there is no `join` function.

Comment: Protip: if you use TypeScript you'll avoid type-safety problems like these.

Comment: you can do `split[i] = finalResult` in the loop then outside loop do `split.join('')`

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this by `split` is possible. first create an array of divided strings (by the delimiter ' ') and then loop around the array and capitalize the first char using the method `toUpperCase` and concat the rest of the string without the first letter using `slice`

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  let split = str.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1);
  }
  return split.join('');
}

console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is'));
```

More about `split` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: So you've joined the 'split' outside the for loop? Why didn't it work inside the for loop in the first place?

Comment: @mmiah You do know _exactly_ what `join()` does, right? I'm curious to hear what you think it does and why you think calling `join()` inside the loop body would produce a meaningful result.

Comment: @mmiah, You want to join the string array after the loop finishes to return the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].substring(1)` in the loop then outside loop do `split.join('')`

Basically you are replacing each word (`split[i]`) with capitalised word. Then in the end join the words.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `join` at all, just declare and initialize `finalResult` outside the loop and concatenate each word inside the loop:

```
function generateHashtag(str) {

    const split = str.split(' '); // Array<String>
    let finalResult = ''; // String

    for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

        const titleCased = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].substring(1);
        finalResult += titleCased;
    }

    return finalResult;
}

console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is'));
```

- However, you can simplify this code considerably by using a functional-programming (FP) style with `map` and `reduce`. See below.
- I've also changed your code to use `toLocaleUpperCase` instead of `toUpperCase` and uses `[0]` for brevity.
- It's still safe to use `substring(1)` for single-character strings, it just returns `''`.

```
function generateHashtag(str) {
    return ( str
        .split(' ')
        .map( word => word[0].toLocaleUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLocaleLowerCase() )
        .reduce( ( word, concat ) => concat + word, "" )
    );
}
```

---

- I forgot that `join()` can still be used instead of `reduce` (and will have an optimized implementation inside the JS engine anyway):
- I've also moved the `map` function's logic to a named function `toTitleCase`.

```
function generateHashtag(str) {
    
    const toTitleCase( word ) => word[0].toLocaleUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLocaleLowerCase();

    return ( str
        .split(' ')
        .map( word => toTitleCase( word ) ) // or just `.map( toTitleCase )`
        .join()
    );
}
```

The `return` statement has parens to prevent unwanted automatic-semicolon-insertion which would otherwise break the function.

Answer (score 0):

finalResult is a String, not an Array so there is no join function.

Use this instead :

```js
function generateHashtag (str) {

 let arrayWords = str.split(' ')
 const titleCasedArray = arrayWords.map(word => titleCaseWord(word))
 return titleCasedArray.join('');

}

function titleCaseWord (word){
  return word.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1,-1).toLowerCase()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
  //returns array of strings
  let split = str.split(' ') 
  //returns array of strings with each word capitalized
  const capitalizedWordsArr = split.map( word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
  //returns a string by joining above array with no spaces
  return capitalizedWordsArr.join('') 
}
```

Comment: Your `let split` can be `const split` btw.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript strings are immutable so you cannot overwrite them on the go, but you can overwrite array elements.

By using `String.prototype.substr()` you can extract a part of the string, you can use these parts, modify it and create a new string then replace the old array element. finally returning the joined string like you wanted to

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {

    const split = str.split(' ') // array of words

    for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
        split[i] = split[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + split[i].substr(1); // overwriting existing elements with Titlecased words

    return split.join('');  // returning final string

}

console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use-case for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  return str
    .split(' ')
    .reduce((acc, [firstLetter, ...rest]) => acc += `${firstLetter.toUpperCase()}${rest.join('')}`,
    ''
  );
}
console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is')); // should return ('HelloMyNameIs')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to your code, but working, i would do this:

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
  let split = str.split(' ')
  let newStr = []

  for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    newStr.push(split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].substring(1))
  }

  return newStr.join('')
}
```

You could also choose to do this task using a 'regular expression'.
**https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/**

Here is a quick implementation:

```
const generateHashtag = str => {
  // regular expression to capitalize the words
  const regEx = /(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g
  str = str.replace(regEx, (char) => {
    return char.toUpperCase()
  });

  // remove spaces, return
  return str.split(' ').join('')
}
```

Same code, but with less readability:

```
const generateHashtag = str => {
  return str.replace(/(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g, (char) => {
    return char.toUpperCase()
  }).split(' ').join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateHashtag (str) {
    return str.replace(/\b\S/g, e => e.toUpperCase()).replace(/\s/g,'');
}

console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is'))
```

\b: bondary \S: non space \s: space.
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score -1):

```js
//try this code solve your problem 

const generateHashtag = str => {
    let split = str.split(' ')
    let finalResult = []
    for (word of split) {
        finalResult.push(word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
    }
    return finalResult.join('')
}

console.log(generateHashtag('Hello my name is'))
```